# Timer Tick Event and Thread in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I have a timer named `SendTimer`, the interval is 30 secs.

```
protected void SendTimer_Tick(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
      SendTimer.Enabled = false;

      TransferMoney();

      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);

      GenerateTransactions();

      SendTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

I expected tick event to be called correctly by one thread at the same time. NOT by 2 threads simultaneously. but as I saw in my LOGS it seems to be called by a thread while another thread was in action. Any Idea? Because I disable and enable it respectively.

Comment: What timer type are you using?

Comment: So, you have 2 threads that must use that timer, and you do not want them to run simultaneously? Why not to use 'lock' in timer then?

Comment: The code of the tick event will be executed on the GUI thread for `Windows.Forms.Timer`. Are you sure you're using this timer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Forms [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) is a single-threaded by definition. It has nothing about multithreading, because it elapses via [WM_TIMER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, being sent to current GUI thread message queue.

So, this:

> NOT by 2 threads simultaneously

is incorrect, because even if you have several threads, WinForms Timer has nothing to do with this.

Comment: so you say enable and disable is unnecessary?

Comment: @Dennis - not sure that's correct. AFAIK, WM_TIMER 'messages' are synthesised when a GUI thread makes a GetMessage() call and an event flag is set in the Windows Message Queue internal data.  There is one flag for each timer class, it has no count and can only be set once - if it's alredy set, nothing happens.  It is therefore not posssible for WM_TIMER messages to queue up.

Comment: @MartinJames: you're right, my comment contains inaccuracy, I'll fix it.

Comment: @levi: I haven't said this. :) Single-threaded nature of WM_TIMER only guarantees, that message handlers (SendTimer_Tick method in your case) will be called in GUI thread. But, if the timer is enabled, and WM_TIMER handler executes too long (comparing to elapse interval), you'll get next handler call immediately right after current handler call will return.

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST");
        }


in this scenario there should stay one message box until it is clicked, but it is shown a lot?..

Comment: @levi: the problem with `MessageBox` API is related to its own message loop: "To process messages for the modal dialog box, the system starts its own message loop, taking temporary control of the message queue for the entire application. When the system retrieves a message that is not explicitly for the dialog box, it dispatches the message to the appropriate window." So, when message box is visible, and WM_TIMER arrives, message loop of `MessageBox` sends it to application message loop, and timer elapses again and again.

Comment: @levi: this is also true for `Form.ShowDialog`. This link will be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#modal_boxes. But, without showing dialog in WM_TIMER handler, the behavior will be like described in comment above. I've a little mixed up these two behaviors. Note, that there still will be **the same GUI thread**. This is still not a multithreading.